# How do I read the setup eventlog on windows 7

Tags: event-log

I have some C++ code which reads the Application, Security or System eventlogs quite happily using OpenEventLog and ReadEventLog API calls.
I want to read the Setup eventlog on Windows 7 so I pass "Setup" as the log name into OpenEventLog but I just get back the contents of the Application log (which is the documented behaviour for unknown logs).
How do I read the Setup eventlog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this.
Because the setup eventlog is a new format log it can only be opened using the new API calls EvtQuery, EvtNext etc., the old OpenEventLog/ReadEventLog functions do not work on it.

Comment: If we want to get only last event with Specific "Event-id" then is it possible?

Comment: It looks as if this should be possible. The Query parameter is an XPath expression, so specifying something like Event/System[EventID=4] and asking for the Reverse direction may work